# jQuery toggle span class when link is clicked

Tags: jquery, toggle

When clicking $menulink, I would like the span inside .menu-link to have it's class toggled. I tried the code below, but I am doing something wrong because it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').addClass('js');
var $menu = $('#menu'),
$menulink = $('.menu-link'),
$arrow = $('.arrow-down');

$menulink.click(function() {
$menulink.toggleClass('active');
$menu.toggleClass('active');
$arrow.toggleClass('visible');
return false;
});});
})();
```

The markup:

```
<a class="menu-link" href="#menu"><span class="arrow-down"></span><span>Menu</span></a>
<nav role="navigation" id="menu" class="">
<ul class="menu">
<li>stuff</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Any help would be very greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Though this isn't the cause of the problem, when you're selecting elements, if you only expect one result you should be using an id, if you're expecting more than 1 result you should use class and use the `.each()` method to iterate over every matched element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$menulink.find('span').toggleClass('active');
```

if you want only first span then

```
$menulink.find('span:first').toggleClass('active');
```

or want span with having `arrow-down` class

```
$menulink.find('span.arrow-down').toggleClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$menulink.children('span').toggleClass('whatever');
```

inside the click function.

Or if you want to target only `arrow-down` span

```
$menulink.children('span.arrow-down').toggleClass('whatever');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$menulink.children(':first').toggleClass('active');
```

this finds the first child which is `<span>` in your case

Answer (score 0):

The code you use will toggle all elements with that class on the page. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.menu-link').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $(this).children('.arrow-down').toggleClass('visible');
      $('#menu').toggleClass('active');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that because `$menu-link` is an anchor tag, the browser is navigating away from the page?

I don't see why any of the above answers would work if yours doesn't.

try setting up a jsfiddle?